# ColumnLayout alignment options are disabled

Tags: qt, layout, qml, alignment

I'm using a QML `ColumnLayout`. When I review it with Qt Design Studio, I see that all alignment options are disabled:

[image: Qt Design Studio Screenshot]

I wonder why.

---

My `ColumnLayout` is inside a `Rectangle` and contains some buttons:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors {
        top: parent.top
        bottom: parent.bottom
        right: parent.right
    }
    width: // ...

    ColumnLayout {
        id: toolsColumn
        width: // ...

        ToolbarButton {
            // ...
        }

        ToolbarButton {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Also, such statements inside `ColumnLayout` won't take effect:

```
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
```

Comment: align should be applied to the Layout's item, not to the layout itself.

Comment: @folibis Do you mean it should be applied to `ColumnLayout ` children, *not* `ColumnLayout ` itself?

Comment: Since you doesn't provide any informative code I can't say what exactly you do wrong, but yes, `Layout.alignment` as all the attached properties should be attached to a child item. See the [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html#details) for more info. Simple logic will suffice - what if you want to align one item to the left and another one to the right, how can you do that by defining the alignment of the `ColumnLayout` itself?